# What size is a maze runner?

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded

One of my players has taken the Captain Edge, which gives them a maze runner of their very own. However, it doesn't give any information in the books as to how big it is.

How big is a maze runner, either in battlemat inches or real world measurements?

Answer (score 7):

After looking through several books from *Deadlands Reloaded* and *Deadlands Classic*, I am surprised to say that there does not seem to be any official mention of how big a maze runner is. There also seems to be very few pictures of a maze runner itself, which is odd given its importance in that area of the Weird West. Another answer mentioned that there is the *Deadlands d20* 'Rats in the Maze' adventure that includes a maze runner figure flat, but as noted there is no grid and it's not clear if it is intended to be to scale (8" = 48' for the length of the ship seems a little small, so it sounds to me like they just made it as large as the paper would allow them).

However, there was a 4 issue *Deadlands* comic anthology series published in 2011 and early 2012 and the last issue, [Black Water](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/101681/DEADLANDS-Black-Water), took place in the Great Maze with the characters boarding a maze runner at one point. From the images, we can see how large this particular maze runner was:

[image: Maze runner at dock]

Notice the man standing on the lower dock near one of the signature paddle wheels, which gives some perspective. Given his size in relation to the maze runner, I'd guess that it's at least 20 feet from the dock he's standing on to the deck, and the runner itself is maybe 125-150 feet long (20-25 battlemat inches).

The deck is pretty spacious too; the characters seem to have a lot of room (about 6 feet between the railing and the structure, which is conveniently equal to 1 battlemat inch):

[image: Passengers on the deck]

In relation to the Great Maze itself (or this particular area of it), the maze runner has room, but not much of it. It would be difficult to have two try to pass each other. Notice also the size of the two lifeboats and the size of the man standing at the front of the maze runner.

[image: In the Great Maze]

Below decks there is enough space for a dining area (and presumably living space as well) large enough for nine people...and a horse!

[image: The dining area]

I would imagine that maze runners come in all sizes depending on their purpose (passengers, cargo, etc.) and how wide the straits will be that they're traveling through, much like the real world steam boats that they are based upon. The *Smith and Robbards 1880 Catalog* says that a maze runner requires 3 crew and can take up to 5 passengers, so the maze runner in the pictures is probably a bit larger than average since it can take more passengers.

If we assume that the size of the maze runner in the 'Rats in the Maze' adventure is to scale and an example of a smaller maze runner and the one in the comic is a larger one, then maze runners typically range from 48 feet to 150 feet long (8 to 25 battlemat inches). Personally I'm inclined to lean towards the larger figure given the size of steamboats I've seen, but I imagine you could make it anywhere within that range, or a bit beyond, if you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

From [Savage Worlds - Deadlands Reloaded - Smith & Robards Catalog](http://tarsis.org/me/mikeg/savage%20worlds%20-%20deadlands%20reloaded%20-%20smith%20&%20robards%20catalog.pdf) (you may have some similar listing for Deadlands Reloaded equipment; this was a quick Google Search result), The maze runner is a "standard boat ... equipped with the basic hull", which should be listed in the Savage Worlds core book with real-world measurements.

I will update my answer later today, as I don't have the core book to hand at the moment and want to check, but I'm confident enough there'll be measurements in there.

**EDIT:**

Having checked the core book, there isn't a set standard "size" for boats, or even what a "standard" boat is, but reading the entry in the link above describes the Maze Runner as a standard paddle boat, and the crew + passengers is roughly equivalent to a yacht (from the core book). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There was a Figure flat for the Classic Deadlands :Great Maze Box set. The mat was approximately 10" x 6" meaning you had a boat 60ft by 36ft. This was for the more personal maze runner . From the books description it appears there was a wide variety in the sizes. Remember that they are considered a Mad Science  device so each is a rather unique item. Also according to the Smith and Robards source book(52-53) it had space for 8 passengers, slightly more then a sreamwagon at 6 , so the size above would be about right.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31395&highlight=maze%20runner) post, maze runners are approximately 10.5 by 4 inches not including the width of the paddles. However, those dimensions are not necessarily equivalent to those used on a Savage Worlds battlemat, and there is no direct reference to any scale.

There is also a figure flat image in the 'Rats in the Maze' adventure available for Deadlands D20, but rather unhelpfully there is no obvious grid or scale to show how many squares it takes up. As a guesstimate, I would make it around 4 by 8 inches, or 8 by 16 yards in real world measurements.